# Why is dynamic textbox returning empty value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Created a basic input textbox and a button dynamically via javascript using some bootstrap css. On pressing the button I need to retrieve the value of the textbox. But its coming out to be empty (not undefined).

The doSearch function is where I need to pick up the value.

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9u3kb6rk/3

Here is the code:

```
(function ($) {

            function doSearch() {
                alert($('#name').val());//this is empty?
            }

            $(document.body).on('click', '#go', function () {
                alert('doing search');
                doSearch();
            });

            $.fn.searchName = function () {
                var caller = $(this);
                var output = '';

                output += '<div class="input-group ">';
                output += '<span class="input-group-addon area" id="name" name="name">Name</span>';
                output += '<input type="text" class="form-control" />';
                output += '</div>';

                output += '<div class="input-group">';
                output += '<span class="input-group-btn">';
                output += '<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="go">Search</button>';
                output += '</span>';
                output += '</div>';
                output += '</div>';

                $(caller).html(output);
                return this;
            }
        }(jQuery));

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#searchName').searchName();
        });
```

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Your fiddle doens't do anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` must be in the `input` instead of in the `span`.

```
output += '<span class="input-group-addon area">Name</span>';
output += '<input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control"
```

Your [code](http://jsfiddle.net/9u3kb6rk/1/) updated.